# IndexError: list index out of range (Python)

Tags: python, loops, indexing, range

I have copypasta'd a python code from a youtube video which should basically allow me to extract the titles and the links from a RSS feed.

```
import urllib.request
import re

webpage= urllib.request.urlopen("http://feeds.feedburner.com/JohnnyWebber?format=xml").read()

heading = re.compile(b'<title>(.*)</title>')
link    = re.compile(b'<link>(.*)</link>')

findheading= re.findall(heading,webpage)
findlink = re.findall (link,webpage)

lists=[]
lists[:]=range(2,16)

for i in lists:
    print (findheading[i])
    print (findlink[i])
    print ("\n")
```

I am getting the error in

```
 print (findheading[i])
```

EDIT:

Another question, After following unutbu's answer, I have been able to get the output but it is like

```
b'HEADING'
b'TITLE'
```

but if I remove the b from the regular expression , then I get a error for using a string instead of a byte like object

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Hardly matters here, does it? Python 3, judging by the `urllib.request` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lists[:]=range(2,16)` creates a list of numbers from 2 to 15:

```
In [11]: range(2, 16)
Out[11]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The error implies that there are fewer than 16 elements in `findheadings`.

---

So instead of relying on the arbitrary assumption that there are a certain number of elements in `findheadings`, in Python it is more idiomatic to use

```
for heading in findheadings
```

to iterate over the elements of `findheadings`. `heading` will 
be assigned to a value in `findheadings` with each pass through the loop.

---

To loop over both `findheading` and `findlink`, use [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for heading, link in zip(findheading, findlink):
    print(heading)
    print(link)
```

Note that if there are a different number of elements in `findheading` and `findlink` then `zip` will stop when there are no more elements in the shorter of the two. Use [itertools.zip_longest](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) if you want to iterate until both are exhausted.